# Improving reprojection accuracy

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, wgs84, utm

How can I improve the accuracy of my reprojection?

I am combining my dataset to a previous one, and I have chosen a different CRS: the previous one is in WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) and mine is in WGS 84 / UTM zone 36S (EPSG:32736). This allows me to get more accuracy in measurements, and is also easier as I'm using meters (from what I've understood and experienced using functions in QGIS).
**Both rawdata were obtained in WGS 84 EPSG:4326, but I reproject mine before doing any work on it. I would prefer keeping on using a mercator as the map unit is in meters and zone 36S is the relevant one for my study area.**

My project aims at counting points inside the squares, calculate area of intersecting polygons, calculate dispersion.

- previous dataset in EPSG:4326: calculation has been done.
- my dataset in EPSG:32736 / UTM zone 36S: the study area is the same + an additional area. Not analysed yet.

To be able to combine the datasets I performed a reprojection with the older datasets using the option "reproject layer" from the toolbox (QGIS 2.18), but the result is slightly off. This can be seen looking at these 2 grids:

[image]

these grids are made of 1x1 km cells. pink grid reprojected from WGS 84 / EPSG:4326 to UTM zone 36S EPSG:32736, white grid created under WGS 84 / UTM zone 36S EPSG:32736.

I have read a couple of questions dealing with similar topics, but it gets a bit too difficult for me who is fairly new to GIS and have never coded before. What I have come up with as solutions so far:

- using a different reprojection of the zone 36S, though I'd rather avoid to, and I'm not sure that would make a difference in the accuracy
- it might simply be that the result cannot be improved as it is a fine scale. In that case I'm wondering whether it is a problem or not that the reprojection is slightly off.
- I could also just use the EPSG:4326 since my data were primarily in this format, and deal with the conversion from degree to meters but it is not easy and less accurate from what I have noticed so far.
- I could enable the OTF but from what I have understood, measurements would be wrong since the CRS don't have the same map units.

I have never worked with projections.

Comment: In the grid created in WGS 84, the cell dimensions are probably not exactly 1 x 1 km. They are more likely measured in decimal degrees, because that's the unit used by that coordinate reference system.

Comment: A grid created in one projection is not identical to a grid created in a different projection. The two grids you're displaying are different grids, so of course they don't align. I think you should pick one grid and use the same grid for all your analyses.

Comment: @csk think of turning your comment into an answer.

Comment: thanks, I have managed to create a grid in EPSG:4326 for both study areas. It makes it a bit more complicated to deal with degrees. I guess if I reproject all my data in UTM I will still have the small reprojection error as seen from the pink grid, how could this be corrected for?

Comment: The difference between the black and pink grids doesn't sound like a reprojection error. It sounds like they actually represent different areas. Are your other layers misaligned when you re-project them? How are you verifying that? Are you comparing point locations to known points on a base layer? Eg, taking a point at the corner of a building, then comparing the location of that point to the visible location of that building on a satellite image.

Comment: It is the same area. I built the black grid based on the red one. And the red grid would be confunded with the black one if there was not a slight reprojection error. I actually tested with a point on 4326 and then reprojecting in UTM zone 36S EPSG:32736, using QGIS and epsg.io

Comment: There is a difference in the reprojection of 0.32 map unit (North) which makes quite a difference when I check the point. I.e. I get ******.8682 (QGIS), ******.85 (epsg.io), and *******.6573 (QGIS), *******.97 .
I'm still wondering whether I could improve this by modifying the reprojection algorithm or not.